# Impossible to start Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, rubygems, sidekiq

After installing Sidekiq on Centos, I try to launch Sidekiq (it's used by Sidekiq), using command:

```
bundle exec sidekiq
```

But then I get:

```
tupromail@be-s2534-msl:~/cuttlefish-master$ bundle exec sidekiq
Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
bundler: command not found: sidekiq
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

Point is that Sidekiq was installed, I see it when I run

```
bundle install
```

I see:

```
Using sidekiq 3.3.0
```

Also, it seems that Sidekiq executables are there:

```
tupromail@be-s2534-msl:~/cuttlefish-master$ gem uninstall sidekiq
Remove executables:
    sidekiq, sidekiqctl

in addition to the gem? [Yn]
```

Any idea?

Comment: list the version by using this command `gem list sidekiq`.

Comment: It's version 3.3.0:

    tupromail@be-s2534-msl:~/cuttlefish-master$ gem list sidekiq

    *** LOCAL GEMS ***

    sidekiq (3.3.0)

Comment: Have you tried `gem install bundler` as suggested in the error message?

Comment: Whats the error after you did bundle install?

Comment: After a gem install sidekiq, I try to run sidekiq with: bundle exec sidekiq, and then I get: bundler: command not found: sidekiq

Comment: are you using rvm or rbenv ?

Comment: make sure you're loading the correct gemset.

Comment: No, not using rvm or rbenv...

Comment: check your Gemfile.lock for the sidekiq version

Answer (score -1):

Update bundler to the latest version, then:

`bundle install sidekiq`

then try again, this issue happened because the bundler version is not the same as the one in the Gemfile.lock

Comment: It should be `gem install sidekiq` or put sidekiq as a gem inside Gemfile and then run `bundle install`.